# Why is \clip a command in TikZ rather than an environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In TikZ one can use the \scope-environment to apply \clip-commands only for a certain part of the TikZ-code. In other words the \scope-environment is used to start and end clipped sections. Is there a reason why it is designed like this? Wouldn't it be more natural if the clipping itself would be an environment and we could forget about the whole \scope thing?

For example like this:

```
\begin{clip}{(0,0) circle (1cm)}
\draw ...
\end{clip}
```

Comment: you can have more than one clipping path, they combine. How would you write this with your syntax?

Comment: Well, Your proposal feels pretty equivalent to `\begin{scope}\clip (0,0) circle (1cm);(newline)\draw ... (newline) \end{scope}`. In both cases, you create an environment (hence a scope) and a clipping path. Also, `scope`s cans be used for many things, not only `clip`s. Moreover, a `\clip` or `\path clip` (which is the same),  follows the same syntax than other `\path` related commands. So it is a way I suppose to avoid creating multiple formats for parsing commands. Otherwise one should create an environment for all possible options based on `scope` e.g `xshift` `yshift`.

Comment: (continued) This could be cumbersome and would be less flexible than the `scope` `key=value` option syntax.

Comment: I believe the one and only reason is that this is how PDF (and probably PostScript) handles clipping, so there is no reason Ti*k*Z would invent a new interface. It basically works as follows: you tell PDF a path, and then you tell whether you want to draw, fill, clip, or any combination using that path. So I consider the current design *natural*. Using `clip` with `scope` is also the natural way (the only proper way) as it is recommended in the PDF specification that use `W` with `q` and `Q`.